# Reading output into variables inside the os.system command

Tags: python, linux, awk, os.system

I have a `python` script which runs in `Linux`. I need to capture a command's output and store into variables and then should print the output. Code below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, time
systime=os.popen('date +"%m-%d-%y-%T"').read()
os.system("read c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 < <(sar -u 1 1 | awk 'NR==4, NR==4 {print $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9}')")
os.system("echo $systime,$c1,$c2,$c3,$c4,$c5,$c6 >> outputfile.txt")
```

I'm collecting the output given by the command `sar -u 1 1 | awk 'NR==4, NR==4 {print $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9}')` into 6 variables - `c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 c6` using the read command. When i try to execute the above code, I get the below error -

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
```

I even tried using `os.popen` instead of `os.system` but still end up getting the same error. Suggest me on how to store the variables using `os.system` command how to use them in the later stages. My target here is to print all the variables including the time being captured into a output file `outputfile.txt`. TIA

Comment: os.system will use `/bin/sh` by default, not bash. Also, each os.system call will spawn a brand new shell, so the variables you want to define in the first one will **not** be available in the second one. What is it about this task that you cannot do in python?

Comment: I'm unable to save the output of the command `os.system("read c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 < <(sar -u 1 1 | awk 'NR==4, NR==4 {print $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9}')")` into the variables `c1, c2,...c6`, while using `os.system`. How can i do that.

Comment: /bin/sh does not implement the process substitution syntax `<()`. Seriously, why are you doing this in python?

Comment: the requirement is to do it in python

Comment: but is the requirement to try to do it in /bin/sh with a thin python wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I mean when I say "what is it about this task that you cannot do in python":

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from subprocess import run, PIPE
from datetime   import datetime

output = run(['sar','-u','1','1'], stdout=PIPE).stdout.decode()
line = output.split("\n")[3]    # 4th line
values = line.split()[-6:]      # last 6 fields

now = datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%y-%T")

print(",".join([now] + values))
```

Comment: Note that I'm not really a python guy, so this may not be the best style.